# Scipy in Jupiter

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, sklearn-pandas

Can someone help me to figure out why i'm having this error code : **ValueError: n_components must be < n_features; got 10 >= 0**

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
users = pd.read_table(open('ml-1m/users.dat', encoding = "ISO-8859-1"), sep=':', header=None, names=['user_id', 'gender', 'age', 'occupation', 'zip'])
ratings = pd.read_table(open('ml-1m/ratings.dat', encoding = "ISO-8859-1"), sep=':', header=None, names=['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating', 'timestamp'])
movies = pd.read_table(open('ml-1m/movies.dat', encoding = "ISO-8859-1"), sep=':', header=None, names=['movie_id', 'title', 'genres'])
MovieLens = pd.merge(pd.merge(ratings, users), movies)

ratings_mtx_df = MovieLens.pivot_table(values='rating', index='user_id', columns='title', fill_value=0)
movie_index = ratings_mtx_df.columns

from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
recom = TruncatedSVD(n_components=10, random_state=101)
R = recom.fit_transform(ratings_mtx_df.values.T)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-0bd6c9bda95a> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
      2 recom = TruncatedSVD(n_components=10, random_state=101)
----> 3 R = recom.fit_transform(ratings_mtx_df.values.T)

C:\Users\renau\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\truncated_svd.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    168             if k >= n_features:
    169                 raise ValueError("n_components must be < n_features;"
--> 170                                  " got %d >= %d" % (k, n_features))
    171             U, Sigma, VT = randomized_svd(X, self.n_components,
    172                                           n_iter=self.n_iter,

ValueError: n_components must be < n_features; got 10 >= 0
```

Comment: The problem is with the shape of input to that `transform` call.  It's an array derived from the dataframe.  Check its shape/size.  Why the `csr` in title?  You haven't created a sparse matrix.

Comment: hpaulj, can you give me more details? Sorry I don't get it... You mean this part : users = pd.read_table(open('ml-1m/users.dat', encoding = "ISO-8859-1"), sep='

Comment: Focus on `ratings_mtx_df.values`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to split your data into 10 dimensions, but as per the documentation for [TruncatedSVD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html), the number of features (columns) in your `ratings_mtx_df` data needs to be greater than the number of dimensions/components you're looking to extract. Try `n_components=3` (assuming you've got at least 3 features in your data) and see if that's any better.

Also, you're turning your input data sideways, with the `.T` argument in:

```
R = recom.fit_transform(ratings_mtx_df.values.T)
```

That may result in switching features (columns) for observations(rows) which might explain why the `fit_transform` method isn't working.

Comment: I'm  a newbie in Python and not sure to understand... I guess ill figure it out with some practice .. Ill post in a month! Thanks for your help